# responvie elements arent working correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello there im new on the responsive thing and im havint trouble with this need some help
the left-side and right-side works fine but when i resize the window the left-side dissapears and the right side remains on its original position it does not go to the top.
can any one guide me:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Administrador Veterinario</title>
    <meta name="title" content="Administrador Veterinario"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Administrador Veterinario"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Administrador Veterinario"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../cssVETS/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Heasder Starts Here -->    
        <header class="header">
            <div class="head_content">
            <div id="logo"><a href="administrador.php"><img src="../images/<?php echo logo($vets); ?>" width="150" class="img-rounded" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- menu 
        <nav>
        <div class="menu">----</div>
        </nav>
        -->

<div class="subContenedor">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <aside class="left-side">
        <!-- Left side bar goes here -->
        </aside>

        <!-- content -->
        <section>
        <div class="right-side">
                <!-- Text Content Goes here -->
        </div>
        </section>
</div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <footer class="footer">
        <!-- Footer content goes here -->
        </footer>

    </div> <!-- End of Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; }
a { color: #067aa7; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
img { border: 0; }

article, aside, details, footer, header, menu, nav, section { display: block; }

/* Desing Starts Here */
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper{ 
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;       
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;       
/*  margin: 5px 0 0 0;*/
    background-color:#fff;
}
.subContenedor{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
/*  margin: 5px 0 0 0;*/
    background-color:#FFFFFF;   
}

.left-side{
    float: left;
    width: 200px; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    min-height: 600px; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 600px;  
}
.right-side{
    float: left;
    width: 830px; 
    min-height: 600px; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 600px; 
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
.footer{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;       
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    background-color: #bdc8cd;
}

.logo {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:7px;
}

.avisos {
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:right;
}

/***********************   LINKS   ******************************/
a.btnCAJA {
    display: block;
    width:190px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;     
    font-size: 11px;     
    color:#314559;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding:5px;
}
a.btnCAJA:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color:#000;
}



/* Lets make the Design Responsive */

@media (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1023px) {   /* CSS for browsers less than 1024px*/
    body {  max-width: 920px; }
    .left-side{ width: 200px; }
    .right-side{ width: 700px; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) { /* CSS for browsers less than 960px*/
    body {  max-width: 720px; }
    .left-side{ width: 200px; }
    .right-side{ width: 500px; }  
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px) {   /* CSS for browsers less than 768px*/
    body {  max-width: 580px; }
    .left-side{ width: 200px; }
    .right-side{ width: 360px; }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {   /* CSS for browsers less than 600px*/
    body { max-width: 460px; }
    .header{ width: 450px; border: 3px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px; }
    .menu{ width: 450px; border: 3px solid #007aad; border-radius: 5px; }
    .subContenedor{ width: 450px;   border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;  border-radius: 5px; }
    .left-side{ visibility:hidden;}
    .right-side{ width: 445px;  margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px; position: relative; top:0px; }   
    .footer{  width: 450px;border: 3px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px; }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {   /* CSS for browsers less than 480px*/
    body {  max-width: 310px; }
    .header{ width: 300px; border: 3px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px; }
    .menu{ width: 300px; border: 3px solid #007aad; border-radius: 5px; }
    .subContenedor{ width: 300px;   border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;  border-radius: 5px; }
    .left-side{ visibility:hidden;}
    .right-side{ width: 294px;  margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px; }   
    .footer{  width: 300px;border: 3px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px; visibility:hidden;}
}

@media (max-width: 319px) {  /* CSS For 320px or less browsers */
    body {  max-width: 100%; }
    .left-side{ visibility:hidden;}
    .right-side{ width: 96%; }
}




/* */
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden because you have a bit of CSS doing that (visibility: hidden):

```
.left-side{ visibility:hidden;}
```

You might want to remove that line, or change it for:

```
.left-side { width: 96% }
```

or 100%, it's up to you.

However, it's good practice to hide the navigation in small screens and implement mobile navigation. There are plenty of examples in internet. [This](http://slicknav.com/) is just an example, using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to hide .left-side on smaller screens? Try changing every instance of

```
.left-side{ visibility:hidden;}
```

to

```
.left-side{ display:none;}
```

An element with "visibility: hidden" still takes up space within a document but is invisible. You want to completely remove the element from the flow of the document as well as make it invisible, which is what "display: none" does.